# What is the javascript code to know whether the browser has mp3,audio encoding,video encoding and printing capability?

Tags: javascript

I want a javascript code to know whether our browser has Mp3,audio encoding,video encoding and Printing capability or not.For example if i will click a button on 1st page on the next page i want to see the output like

Mp3 Capable:True/False
Audio Encoding Capabilty: True/False
Video Encoding Capability: True/False
Printing Capabilty: True/False

Comment: You'll have to look up "feature detection".

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com) for feature detection, but if this is not suitable for your case you can test either User Agent (each one supports different audio/video formats) or test for mpeg support (for audio) with this JS code:

```
function isMpegSupported(){
   var elem = document.createElement('audio');
   return !!(elem.canPlayType && elem.canPlayType('audio/mpeg;') !== '');
}
```

(Code inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469145/how-to-detect-html5-audio-mp3-support))

I also suggest reading about the method [canPlayType](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_canplaytype.asp) and about feature detection, [this](http://diveinto.html5doctor.com/detect.html) is a good place to start (also has great info about video format feature detection)

Comment: @user1613252 did this answer not resolve your question, or at least help?

Comment: @user1613252 if my answer did solve your issue can you please mark it as so, else comment and I'll try to help further. Thanks.