# Chrome, addEventListener(): what is going wrong ? What cross-browser alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, chromium, promise

I just found out that `addEventListener()` is dramatically failling on Chrome (28).

My working example is [a text-to-speech **fiddle** where I want to listen and the end of a sound file's play to play the next soundfile](http://jsfiddle.net/n3yRT/1/). In Firefox, all fine. In Chrome, the script break within the first addEventListener.

**What is going wrong, how to fix it ?**

**Do you have a cross-browser proof alternative way to listen at the end of an event ?**

Comment: Working fine in Chrome 31.

Comment: @Fabricio : you get the 2 console mesage, and you can click as many times as you want on the span to get the sound play and the `alert("hello")`?

Comment: Exactly yes. BTW consider using data-attributes for storing element metadata.

Comment: Yet, my trouble is now: how many browser / mobile browser will fails on this one. ;__;

Comment: Browsers that support HTML5 `<audio>` may fail because of format/codec compatibility (see [compat table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility)), you can check whether the user's browser supports the given format via `canPlayType` (see [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8469145/1331430)) and provide alternative formats based on that. And yes, using `<audio>` in a cross-browser way is not very straightforward still.

Comment: Just upgraded to Chromium Version 30.0.1599.114 Ubuntu 13.04 (30.0.1599.114-0ubuntu0.13.04.2), still failing. Hope the 31 will fix it.