# jPlayer searching for ActiveX control in IE8/9/10

Tags: internet-explorer-9, activex, windows-8.1, jplayer

I am trying to develop an WAT(windows application template) app for windows tablet which is supposed to play MP3 files using jPlayer library. Being a WAT app it uses the IE browser built in.

Case I

When opening the page in IE9 I get the message from browser "Allow ActiveX control" when allowing the player works fine.
If I do not click allow the jPLayer does not work.

Case II

On tablet in the WAT app when loading the jPlayer basically nothing happens and the play functionality is not working.

My assumption is that the code is not executed on the WAT app because the I am unable to allow the activeX control so jPLayer can check if flash is installed or not.

Any ideas how this can be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

By WAT/Web App template i assume app you refer to [Web App Template for VS2013](http://wat.codeplex.com/).

First off is that the HTML5 audio tags are working fine in x-ms-webview (which WAT uses underneath).

Secondly you need to use a crossdomain.xml if you have the audio content (mp3 files) hosted on another domain (this is because the content is not trusted).

Plugins are not loaded x-ms-webview, hence if you use a swf player you will not get it running if you use the flash solution.

jplayer uses a fallback mechanism from native audio to flash playing.
A solution is to use the player conditionally and use the html5 audio tag, if audio is available (use the check explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469145/how-to-detect-html5-audio-mp3-support)).

see [x-ms-webview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301831.aspx) for more info.