# .play() doesn´t work in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

This method is working in Chrome, IE etc. , but in Safari doesn't work. I was reading a lot of on this topic, but nothing helped me...
I know that with QuickTime it works. This is a simple code for idea:

HTML

```
<div id="but"></div>
<audio id="first">
        <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</audio>
```

JS

```
$("#but").mousedown(function(){
        songPlay();
    });

    function songPlay()
    {
        var audio = document.getElementById("first");
        audio.play();
    }
```

Much would help me some simple example with solution.

Comment: Does it work if you enable the controls to show and play it manually?

Comment: What is the result of `audio.networkState`, `audio.readyState`, `audio.error` and `audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg')` ?

Comment: In Mozzila this:
NetworkState: 1 ReadySate: 4 Error: null
In Safari this:
NetworkState: undefined ReadySate: undefined Error: undefined

And audio.canPlayType me threw an error, that it doesn't method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further clarification the OP is using safari 5.x on windows platform, that version of safari doesn't support the audio tag **[source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio)**, the solution would be to set a flash fallback or simply ignore that market share since apple killed support for safari on windows.

Comment: What do you think with "flash fallback"?

Comment: I think it isn't needed as you are trying to support a discontinued browser.

Comment: I was quite interested, because I want to my app work on "all" browsers. :)

Comment: You would need to detect if the audio element is supported [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8469184/1401094) and if not toggle a flash alternative, do not there are plenty of libraries that you can use that handle the toggling for you such as [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/)

Comment: @MarkFalex forgot to tag you ^^